# Windows Azure Notification Hub. Push-notifications with Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, push-notification, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

I trying use Python SDK to send push-notifications via Notification Hub accordingly this guide http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues/ I successfully create ServiceBusService. But this code `bus_service.create_queue('taskqueue', queue_options)` returns me an error.

Here stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "push.py", line 12, in <module>
    sbs.create_queue('surflunch', queue_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py", line 205, in create_queue
    _dont_fail_on_exist(ex)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/__init__.py", line 891, in _dont_fail_on_exist
    raise error
azure.WindowsAzureError
```

By the way if I don't create queue I still can send message to server as

```
msg = Message(b'Test Message')
bus_service.send_queue_message('taskqueue', msg)
```

And here comes an interesting thing! Monitor in MS Azure show me that message comes, but that message don't broadcasts to mobile devices like push notification.

Can anyone tell should I create queue? And why notification hub receive my message but don't send it to devices?

Comment: Please take a look at the updated link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues
to send messages using v7 of servicebus. Let me know here if you still get the error